# Continuity of a piecewise function of two variable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

I'm given this equation:

$$
u(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{(x^3 - 3xy^2)}{(x^2 + y^2)}\quad& \text{if}\quad (x,y)\neq(0,0)\\
 0\quad& \text{if} \quad (x,y)=(0,0).
\end{cases}
$$

It seems like L'hopitals rule has been used but I'm confused because

1. there is no limit here it's just straight up $x$ and $y$ equals zero.
2. if I have to invoke limit here to use Lhopitals rule, there are two variables $x$ and $y$. How do I take limit on both of them?

Comment: L'Hopital here makes no sense, since it can be used only in one-variable limits.

Comment: What's the limit you're looking for? You want to verify that at $(x,y)=(0,0)$, the limit is $0$?

Comment: I just want to know how u(0,0) equals 0. If I plug in the zeros for x and y, I get zero over zero.

Comment: The author is *defining* a certain function. (S)he has chosen to define it for $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$ by a certain formula, and wants to also define it at $(0,0)$. One could define $u$ to be $17$ at $(0,0)$. But the author chose to define $u(0,0)$ as being $0$. It turns out that this choice makes $u$ continuous at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option. Write $(x,y)$ in polar form: $x = r\cos(\theta)$, $y = r\sin(\theta)$. You get:

$$u(r,\theta) = \frac{r^3\cos^{3}(\theta) - 3r^3\cos(\theta)\sin^{2}(\theta)}{r^2}$$

$$u(r,\theta) = r[\cos^{3}(\theta) - 3\cos(\theta)\sin^{2}(\theta)]$$

Since $\cos^{3}(\theta) - 3\cos(\theta)\sin^{2}(\theta)$ is continuous, it is bounded. Meaning there exists some $M > 0$ such that $-M < \cos^{3}(\theta) - 3\cos(\theta)\sin^{2}(\theta) < M$.

Then you have $-Mr < u(r,\theta) < Mr$. By the squeeze theorem:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}u(x,y) = \lim_{r \rightarrow 0^{+}}u(r,\theta) = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

u(0,0) can't possibly exist as it would be a division by 0. You haven't given us enough information. What is the point of this equation? What is the problem you have to solve?

Comment: It sounds like part of the function's definition is that $u(0,0)=0$, and for $(x,y)\neq (0,0), u(x,y) = (x^3-3xy^2)/(x^2+y^2)$.

Comment: I haven't indeed! The equation is defined as zero at that point (thanks Batman). I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it is a piecewise definition.  $u(x,y)$ makes sense as long as both $x$ and $y$ are not $0$.  It is probably just to mean that: if $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ then $u(x,y)$ is as defined (with the formula), otherwise $u(x,y)=0$.  You certainly cannot plug in $(0,0)$ to the formula.  It may be that the point is chosen because there is a "hole" and that $0$ would fill in the hole, but this is not necessarily the case.